# Does Dijkstra's algorithm always return the "shortest" (least number of edges) path?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

There are two functions that I wish to minimize:

a. the number of "obstacles" on the path (assume each obstacle increases the cost); and 
b. total number of edges between the source and the destination.

If I had to minimize just (a), I would have used Dijkstra's algorithm; if I had to minimize just (b), I would have used BFS.

But given that I have to minimize *both*, can I use Dijkstra's algorithm *only*?  In other words, if I find the path with the least cost from the obstacles, does Dijkstra's algorithm also guarantee that the path length thus obtained (between source and destination) would be the shortest?

Comment: What if the path with fewest obstacles and the path with fewest edges are different paths? E.g. A to B has 2 obstacles, but A to C and C to B have no obstacles. The path from A to B with fewest obstacles is A-C-B but the path with fewest edges is A-B. There is no single path that is optimal for both.

Comment: "There are two functions that I wish to minimize" You cannot minimize two functions at the same time, unless both happen to have a minimum at the same place.

Comment: By the way, Dijkstra's algorithm is an optimised version of BFS and is suitable for both tasks (but not at the same time of course).

Comment: @RaymondChen, my question is not whether there's a single path that is optimal for both; rather it is: when Dijkstra's finds a shortest path from the source to the destination, is it "shortest" only in terms of the cost function or also in terms of the distance (in terms of number of edges).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. could you please elaborate on "optimized version of BFS"?  When Dijkstra's finds a shortest path from the source to the destination, is it "shortest" only in terms of the cost function or also in terms of the distance (in terms of number of edges).

Comment: Dijkstra replaces the FIFO queue of BFS with a priority queue, that's the difference. There is no such thing as "optimising two functions simultaneously", regardless of the algorithm. Dijkstra can find a shortest path in terms of any *one* distance-like function, you just need to configure the priority queue accordingly.

Comment: I gave an example graph where the shortest-cost path is not the shortest-length path.

Answer (score 1):

When discussing paths on weighted graphs, the term "shortest path" means the path with the lowest total cost.  Think of the weights as distances.  This is the path that Dijkstra's algorithm will find.

You can use any cost function you like, as long as the cost to get from one vertex to another is always positive or zero.  As mentioned in comments, however, you can only minimize one function at a time.  This is a general fact that has nothing to do with Dijkstra's algorithm.

The cost function that you seem to suggesting is perfectly fine -- the cost to move to a normal vertex is 1, while the cost to move to an "obstacle" vertex is higher.  Dijkstra's algorithm is the appropriate way to find a path with lowest total cost.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  Suppose we have a graph with 5 paths from src to dest. 
 Suppose there are two paths `A` and `B` with the _same_ lowest total cost (say, `10`), but one of them (say, `A`) consists of only 4 edges while `B` consists of 5 edges from src to dest.  Is there some guarantee as to which path (`A` or `B`) will Dijkstra return?  Or does it depend upon how I have implemented the priority queue?

Comment: You define what "total cost" means.  If you want the number of edges to be significant, then include a cost for every edge traversed.